# one to many relation emberjs

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

I am facing trouble in getting displayed this json format in ember's handlebar

Here is my model:

```
Office.Customer = DS.Model.extend({
    orders: DS.hasMany('Office.Order',{embedded:true})
})
```

MY order model:

```
Office.Order = DS.Model.extend({
    mode: DS.attr('string'),
    price: DS.attr('string'),
    created_at: DS.attr('string')
});




{
  "orders":
    [
      {
        "id":421,
        "mode":"Paypal",
        "price":"50.0"
      }
    ],
  "customer":
    {
      "id":389,
      "name":"xxx ",
      "email":"xxx@yyy.",
      "jobs":
        [
          {
            "delivery_time":2
          },
          {
            "delivery_time":24
          }
        ],
      "order_ids":
        [
          421
        ]
    }
}
```

I have model with

`orders: DS.hasMany('Office.Order',{embedded:true})`

The above model displays orders: id, mode and value but i cant get jobs delivery_time.

I tried like this to get delivery_time but no luck its not working

```
{{#each ord in orders.customer.jobs}}
```

Using this works fine

```
{{#each order in orders}}
<span>Mode</span>{{order.mode}}
{{/each}}
```

But how can i display that multiple delivery time.

Comment: I've reformatted the JSON code you provided, but I've found several errors, where they errors or just typos? I've not corrected it because maybe this might be on of the problem? have a look

Comment: The thing i pasted is the json format which i get as rails output. How  can i use it in embers handlebar

Comment: I've seen your edit, but your JSON is still wrong, is this exactly what you get from your response? or are there typos? I can see some missing closing brackets etc.

Comment: you have still not answered my question about the JSON format.

Comment: See the edit, again i run my script and got json format like this

Comment: I don't know if you have a copy/paste problem but your JSON is wrong formatted... do you see any any errors in your console? ember should complain about this.

Comment: I am not getting any error in console too i checked.

Comment: @intuitivepixel can you edit the above json format to correct one so that i can check.

Comment: corrected, but it was my mistake, This one is correct, hmm

Comment: @intuitivepixel still am walking through but i couldn't find solution for this one can you help

Comment: can you update your question with both complete model definitions, Office and order?